# How do I use ui-router authentication with Asp.Net?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to integrate ASP.Net 5.0 with AngularJS with Active Directory, but constantly receiving 404 error when accessing "/api/Account/Ping".

ui-router set up:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/list");

        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!').html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
        });

        $stateProvider
        .state('stateIndex', {
                    url: '/',
                    templateUrl: '/templates/list.html',
                    controller: 'dashListController'     
        })
        .state('stateList', {
                    url: '/list',
                    templateUrl: '/templates/list.html',
                    controller: 'dashListController'
        }).state('stateDashboard', {
                    url: '/dashboard',
                    templateUrl: '/templates/dashboard.html',
                    controller: 'dashboardController'
        })
        .state('stateWidgetsList', {
                    url: '/widgetsList',
                    templateUrl: '/templates/widgetsList.html',
                    controller: 'widgetsListController',
                    resolve: {
                        authentication: ['$http', function ($http) {
                            return $http.get('api/Account/Ping');
                        }]
                    }
        });
}]);
```

AccountController:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Account")]
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    [Authorize] 
    [HttpGet, Route("Ping")]
    public IHttpActionResult Ping()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

WidgetsController:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class WidgetsController : Controller
{
    private readonly PMSContext _dbContext;

    public WidgetsController(PMSContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Widget> Get()
    {
        return _dbContext.Widgets;
    }
}
```

I'm using interceptors to route it to login screen., but every time I'm trying to access /widgetsList I get 404 error. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

you should remove / from `templateUrl: '/templates/widgetsList.html'` and it should be `templateUrl: 'templates/widgetsList.html'`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I remove resolve: { ... }, it returns me the page correctly. So the issue is not about routing to widgetsList.html. It is related to api/Account/Ping, which returns 404

Comment: Can you post the complete 404 error which you get in console.

Comment: is the base folder name in webapps missed out in the url.should it be like `localhost:46899/{{deployed folder name}}/api/Account/Ping`

Comment: I don't have any deployment folder and other Api's works, only this one don't